# How many polygons count are reasonable for an Android mobile game ?

Tags: unity, graphics, performance

I'm trying to develop a mobile game but I'm facing issue regarding FPS. 
So my question is: 2016/2017 smartphone hardware, how many polygon counts are reasonable ?

Thanks

Comment: Polygon count is a poor measure to go by.